# What files in published folder are updated when I changes in Controllers are made?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application that I need to deploy, but the problem is the transfer rate is very slow. So when I publish the application, I am just copying the files that have changes. For example, I made a changes in Index view, I would just copy and paste it in my publish folder, instead of publishing the whole project. But when it comes with Controllers, I have no idea on what files are changed. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you can just copy the web binaries/dll to the publish folder?

Comment: There are no dll in the publish folder

Comment: As @BernardG said you might want to check the bin folder. It has to be somewhere within the publish folder. At least deployed to another folder part of the publish process. Otherwise there is no easy way to run the app.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a change to a controller, it's the application.dll who change.
You say there are no Dlls in the published folder, but for what I know, it's not possible!

How do you publish, and how do you check your published site is working ?

For me, a very basic published folder looks like this:

bin

content

scripts

views

Global.asax

Web.config

How do yours looks like?

(DLLs are in the bin folder)